# "Location" permission not getting removed from iPhone Settings of my App

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, appsettings

My App is currently using Corelocation framework to capture locations of user. But for the next release we are planning to remove location capturing feature from the App. We have removed all the codes, capabilities associated with the same. But, "Location" permissions are not getting removed from iPhone Settings of my App. Only doing a fresh installation "Location" permission is not showing. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot revoke the permission once it has been granted by the user. The only way to do that would be for the user to manually revoke it from the device settings app.

You as a developer can stop using the location data and tell the user that they need not allow sharing the location data if they have already granted the permission before.